# Accessing a dictionary member within the same dictionary

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary

I am trying to do something like this:

```
_dict = {"foo" : 1234,
         "bar" : _dict["foo"] + 1}
```

Cant seem to get the syntax correct, is there a way to acomplish this without using multiple dictionaries, or defining them elsewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot access `_dict` *while* defining it. Python first evaluates the `{...}` dict literal before assigning it to `_dict`. In other words, while evaluating the `{...}` dict literal statement, `_dict` is not yet defined and thus cannot be accessed.

Do this instead:

```
_dict = {"foo" : 1234}
_dict["bar"] = _dict["foo"] + 1
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I wanted, thanks for the VERY quick reply :)

Answer (score 9):

You'll can either assign then from the same var:

```
foo = 1234
_dict = {
  "foo" : foo,
  "bar" : foo + 1,
}
```

Or do it with two statements (still the same dict):

```
_dict = { "foo": 1234 }
_dict["bar"] = _dict["foo"] + 1
```

---

If you can elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, perhaps there's a more elegant solution to be found. Often, when one needs to define `dict` value based on another it is because the values are dynamically defined using a parametrised operation. In those cases it is sometimes possible to use list comprehension/generator expression. E.g.

```
>>> dict((v, 1234+i) for i, v in enumerate(("foo", "bar")))
{'foo': 1234, 'bar': 1235}
```

Comment: Unrelated but it's list comprehension/generator expression.